# Laravel - Redirect to login if not authorised, even is route is not registered

Tags: laravel

I'm building an app in Laravel v5.6 which should be entirely behind a login page (except for the login page itself and password reset pages).

I have written a middleware class `CheckAuth` - the essentials are,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->guest() && $this->requestIsNotForGuests($request->path())) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

If an unauthenticated user requests an unregistered route they see a 404 page. Unauthenticated users shouldn't know whether a route exists or not.

**How can I redirect *any* unauthenticated request (excluding the login page itself and password reset pages) to the login page?**

I have tried using route groups with middleware in routes/web.php but this isn't working as expected.

---

**Update...**

I have added the following to the end of `routes/web.php`,

```
Route::any('{any}', function() {
    abort(404);
})->where('any', '.*');
```

This achieves the behaviour I'm after but doesn't feel right - is there a better way?

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` statement read `if (auth()->guest() || $this->isUnauthorisedRequest($request->path()))`

Comment: So if the user is a guest OR is unauthorized for the current request path, redirect to login page

Comment: That will cause an infinite redirect loop. A redirect isn't necessary if a guest requests an allowed route.

Comment: then your method named `isUnauthorisedRequest` should be able to tell that the requested path is authorized for everyone. Either your naming convention here isn't indicative of its functionality or somethings wrong

Comment: OK, I can see how it could be misleading, I've updated the method name to make its functionality clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to wrap all of your routes inside the middleware. It's very common practice. Your middleware dictates the rules and redirects accordingly, either to the route that a user is trying to access if they are authenticated or to a different place/different action if not.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    //Routes you want affected here
});
```

The standard Auth middleware is fine for this, just amend it to what you want to happen if the user isn't authenticated.

**Edit**

Just some common sense, your login page would be outside of the middleware group

** Edit 2 **

After understanding the question better, you are trying to pass any route, even if it doesn't exist through the auth middleware.

Using all the information I typed above you need to now apply this.

Use the standard auth middleware, you do not need to change anything about the middleware, it will do what you require

Wrap your routes, as suggested inside the middleware group, see what I put above, leave out the login routes!

Now add a new Route like the example below **outside** of the middleware group, **this will be outside with the login rotues**

```
Route::get(/{slug}, 'HomeController@redirector');
```

**I must stress that this Route needs to be the last in your web.php**

Now create a method in your HomeController like so:

```
public function redirector($slug)
{
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

Comment: Doing that still means that a guest user requesting a path that does not exist see's a 404 page - they shouldn't - they should be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Those routes will still be defined for everyone, if someone not logged in hits those routes, they would simply be redirected to the login page.  Are you seeing something else that indicates they would get a 404 rather than a redirect?  Possibly your login page is resulting in a 404?

Comment: I think you've mis-understood my post. My requested behaviour was for *any* request (except login and password resets) to redirect to login. I did *not* want a 404 page to be displayed at all for guests.

Comment: As an example - an app has two registered routes - `/login` and `/secret`. My required behaviour is that if a guest enters anything other than `/login` they are redirected to `/login` (even if they enter a non-existent route e.g. `/made-up`). My first attempts resulted in a 404 which I didn't want. Guests shouldn't know if routes exist or not, they should be redirected to `/login` regardless. I have updated my original post with a solution that gives the required behaviour but seems a bit 'hacky'.

Comment: Okay, please see my updated answer, this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, similar to what I put at the end of my updated question. Although I believe your suggestion redirects authenticated users to the login page if they enter an unregistered route, they should get a 404. Have updated the controller to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Auth::guest()) {
   return redirect()->route('route_name');
}
```

without `return $next($request);` (it cause "continuation" of request).

By the way, you can create new route file and register it inside `RouteServiceProvider`. And you didn't specified Laravel version...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show login page instead of 404, you can modify your `\App\Exceptions\Handler::render` method. Just place

```
if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) return redirect('/login');
```

to the first row of this method. And

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

of course.

`$exception->getCode() === 404` not working for me.